# How to display taxonomies instead of categories in my website home page by using WordPress (PHP)?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy called operating_system.In the admin panel I have created a few taxonomy. On the homepage I want to display the taxonomies instead of categories. what can i do to get exact answer.please suggest me a suitable code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<?php 
 $args=array(
    'name' => 'genre'
 );
 $output = 'objects'; // or objects
 $taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output); 
 if  ($taxonomies) {
    foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
      echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->name . '</p>';
    }
 }  
?>
```

You can see more details and examples in the [`codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies).

Comment: its good but it shows all taxonomy name only and included default taxonomy also. i want taxonomy name which i create with post inside of that taxonomy.will u give me suitable code if u know?

Comment: i have already used this code  but the problem is that it was hard coded i want to display taxonomy dynamically now what code i used to get my query?